# OpenGL how to use an integer texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to draw a quad with a texture which pixels are 32 bit `unsigned int` rgba. The texture does not get drawn. It's a black screen. I think it's something to do with the shaders and `glTexImage2D` call; because the quad can be drawn with a static color, the uv is correct, the texture is correct, but `texture(tex, uv)` gets `(0,0,0,0)`. I can't figure out why OpenGL can't get the texture data.

The shaders

```
vertex_shader[0] = "#version 330 core\n\
layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;\n\
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uv;\n\
\n\
out vec2 fuv;\n\
\n\
void main(){\n\
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);\n\
    fuv = uv;\n\
}\n";

fragment_shader[0] = "#version 330 core\n\
uniform usampler2D tex;\n\
in vec2 fuv;\n\
out uvec4 color;\n\
\n\
void main(){\n\
    color = texture(tex, fuv);\n\
}\n";
```

Color the texture

```
unsigned int *Screen_image;
for (int now_y=0; now_y<View_height; now_y++) {
    for (int now_x=0; now_x<View_width; now_x++) {
        Screen_image[now_y*View_width + now_x] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
}
```

Create a quad to fill the viewport.

```
int vertc = 6;
SVertex vertices[vertc] = {
    {{-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f},   {0.0f, 1.0f}},    // top left 
    {{-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},   {0.0f, 0.0f}},   // bottom left
    {{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 1.0f}},   // top right
    {{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 1.0f}},   // top right
    {{-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},   {0.0f, 0.0f}},   // bottom left
    {{1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},   {1.0f, 0.0f}}   // bottom right
};
```

Create the buffers

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &Vao);
glBindVertexArray(Vao);
/*buffer*/  
glGenBuffers(1, &Vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(SVertex)*vertc, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SVertex), (void*)(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(SVertex), (void*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*3));
/*texture*/
Program1 = LoadShaders();
glGenTextures(1, &Tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Tbo);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glUseProgram(Program1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(Program1, "tex"), 0);
```

Send the texture and draw the quad

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8UI, View_width, View_height, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, Screen_image);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

EDIT:

fragment shader debugging. I get a green screen.

```
vec4 c = texture(tex, fuv);\n\
if (c.x<0) {color.x=1.0;}\n\
if (c.y==0) {color.y=1.0;}\n\
```

I'm using this `glTexImage2D` call and get no error. I've also tried the source type of `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` with no change.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, View_width, View_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8, Screen_image);
std::cout << glGetError() << "err\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which pixels are 32 bit unsigned int rgba.

You should not be uploading this as an integer texture. You want a *[normalized](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Normalized_Integer)* integer [image format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format#Color_formats): `GL_RGBA8`, not `GL_RGBA8UI`. And the sampler type should just be `sampler2D`. And the output color should be a `vec4` (and the output image should also use `GL_RGBA8`).

Comment: I replaced those parts and it still doesn't draw the texture. I'm still using the format/type of `GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8`

Comment: @user193661: then you should have gotten an OpenGL error. The `_INTEGER` pixel transfer format is [incompatible with non-integer image formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format). *Always* check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using minmaps which is the default `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`, so I had to set that parameter to another option like `GL_LINEAR` and now the texture gets drawn.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```